# Bootstrap 4 Tooltip Persists, Looks Terrible

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Could you please run the following html test case, to help figure out how to make bootstrap 4 tooltip go away when a button is disabled while the tooltip is over the button? The details concerning my questions are listed in the code.

The stackoverflow editor is not happy with me putting the details into the code as comments, so I will repeat some details here to try to make the editor happy. When a button is disabled while the cursor is hovering over it, the tooltip does not go away, and it looks terrible. Any assistance appreciated.

Thanks

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Tooltip Persists, Looks Terrible</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Bootstrap 4 Tooltip Persists, Looks Terrible</h3>
    <br> "Other button disabled" scenario works fine.
    <br> First, hover over buttons. Look at tooltips while hovering.
    <br> Then, click button A to disable button B. Works fine:
    <br> - Button B is disabled, and no tooltip.
    <br> - Tooltip still works correctly on button A.
    <br> <br>
    <button type="button" id="button_a" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disables Button B" onclick='change_button ("button_b", true);'>
    Button A
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="button_b" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disabled by Button A">
    Button B
    </button>
    <br> <br> <hr>
    <br> "Same button disabled" scenario fails.
    <br> First, hover over Button C. Look at the tooltip.
    <br> Then, click button C to disable button C. Messes up:
    <br> - Button C is disabled, so that part is OK.
    <br> - But Button C tooltip persists, looks terrible.
    <br> <br>
    <button type="button" id="button_c" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disables Button C" onclick='change_button ("button_c", true);'>
    Button C
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="button_d" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Enables Button C" onclick='change_button ("button_c", false);'>
    Button D
    </button>
    <br> <br> <hr> <br>
    So if a button is disabled while the cursor is hovering over it, the tooltip persists.
    <strong>
    Could you please explain how to make tooltip go away when Button C is disabled?
    </strong>
    I would prefer if tooltip went away when Button C disabled,
    since that is default behavior of bootstrap disabled buttons.
    And disabled button may later get enabled again, so I do not want to delete title attribute.
    Basically I want bootstrap to behave the same way as when Button B is disabled.
    I have looked around and cannot find how to fix this problem,
    and have tried various things, with no success.
    There are real instances where a button carries out an action,
    and then the button needs to be disabled, so I appreciate the help. Thanks
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();});
    function change_button (button_id, bool_val) {
    var button_obj = document.getElementById (button_id);
    button_obj.disabled = bool_val;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add into your `change_button()` function the logic to [`hide`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#tooltiphide), [`disable`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#tooltipdisable) and [`enable`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#tooltipenable) the tooltips.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

function change_button(button_id, bool_val) {
  var button_obj = document.getElementById(button_id);
  button_obj.disabled = bool_val;

  // Disable tooltip
  if (bool_val) {
    $('#' + button_id).tooltip('hide').tooltip('disable');
  } else {
    $('#' + button_id).tooltip('enable');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <br> "Other button disabled" scenario works fine.
  <br> First, hover over buttons. Look at tooltips while hovering.
  <br> Then, click button A to disable button B. Works fine:
  <br> - Button B is disabled, and no tooltip.
  <br> - Tooltip still works correctly on button A.
  <br> <br>
  <button type="button" id="button_a" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disables Button B" onclick='change_button ("button_b", true);'>
    Button A
    </button>
  <button type="button" id="button_b" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disabled by Button A">
    Button B
    </button>
  <br> <br>
  <hr>
  <br> "Same button disabled" scenario fails.
  <br> First, hover over Button C. Look at the tooltip.
  <br> Then, click button C to disable button C. Messes up:
  <br> - Button C is disabled, so that part is OK.
  <br> - But Button C tooltip persists, looks terrible.
  <br> <br>
  <button type="button" id="button_c" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Disables Button C" onclick='change_button ("button_c", true);'>
    Button C
    </button>
  <button type="button" id="button_d" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" title="Enables Button C" onclick='change_button ("button_c", false);'>
    Button D
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your addition works perfectly for the test case. I don't know jquery but can probably make it work in the production version. However, any chance a simpler alternative using a bootstrap or CSS parameter? Or is jquery required to make this work? Thanks again

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#methods), Bootstrap methods run through jQuery. So you *need* jQuery and you are *using* Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, I understood your points, but thanks for emphasizing them. By saying " a bootstrap or CSS parameter", I meant a CSS class to perhaps add, or some modification to an existing bootstrap CSS class. Obviously, it is simpler if some way that bootstrap can be configured at one point, instead of having to write jquery code. Anyway, thanks for verifying I need jquery to fix the problem, and for showing me the way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy tooltip after button disabled.

```
  function change_button(button_id, bool_val) {
    var button_obj = document.getElementById(button_id);
    $("#" + button_id).tooltip("hide");
    button_obj.disabled = bool_val;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your addition also works perfectly for the test case, and is just one simple line. Again, I don't know jquery (I'm very good at javascript, css, html, avoided jquery), so I appreciate your expertise with the (to me) obscure syntax. Again, any chance a simpler alternative using a bootstrap or CSS parameter? Any idea which current solution is "better"? Thanks again

Comment: Because tooltip is not a jquery function, It is provided by bootstrap. So you can control its properties by bootstrap js itself.
Here you can check all available options for BS tooltip https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp

Comment: It was difficult for me to figure out which answer was "most helpful". I chose your answer because 1) shorter / simpler, 2) you answered first, and 3) I needed to pick someone. Both answers were quite helpful. If anyone else has answers or comments, I am interested to hear.

Comment: @user3133452 keep in mind that the answers are not the same. This answer just *hides* the tooltip the first time, but if you hover the button again while being disabled, it will show the tooltip. That's why I did both things (hide and disable) and then re enable it.

Comment: @user3133452, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see my new answer I posted. When I tested with firefox, the hover tooltip did show when Button C was disabled, which azeos suggested might happen. I have not done any mobile tests yet, so that remains unclear. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am original poster. I was surprised by azeos suggesting that behavior was different between the two answers, since I saw no difference in my test browsers IE 11 and chrome 74. So I did more testing with the two answers so far. Both answers modify change_button function in original post:

```
function change_button(button_id, bool_val) { /* A */
  var button_obj = document.getElementById(button_id);
  $("#" + button_id).tooltip("hide");
  button_obj.disabled = bool_val;
  }
```

//////

```
function change_button(button_id, bool_val) { /* B */
  var button_obj = document.getElementById(button_id);
  button_obj.disabled = bool_val;
  if (bool_val) {
    $('#' + button_id).tooltip('hide').tooltip('disable');
    }
  else {
    $('#' + button_id).tooltip('enable');
    }
  }
```

To clarify, the correct (consistent with other bootstrap tooltips) behavior is:

- Load page
- Button C has tooltip on hover
- Click Button C
- Button C is disabled **and** Button C tooltip goes away
- Click Button D
- Button C is enabled and has tooltip on hover again

Here are results of my further testing:

- IE 11 (windows): both answers A and B work
- chrome 74 (windows): both answers A and B work
- opera 60 (windows): both answers A and B work
- safari 10 (mac): both answers A and B work
- **firefox 67 (windows): answer A fails, B works.**

With firefox 67, Button C tooltip did not go away, as azeos suggested might be a problem.

When I have more time, I will do more testing. Also, I posted to twbs/bootstrap on github to report this as a bug, or at least an issue, and will be following any responses.

I used lambdatest website for safari test. I did other tests directly on a windows 7 desktop.

Any other comments or suggestions would be appreciated, such as any tests that make answer B fail, or any smartphone tests.

Comment: I did some more testing: safari on iphone: both answers A and B work. chrome on android phone (galaxy note ii): answer A fails, B works. Again, the failure is that Button C tooltip persists, does not go away. So answer B works fine, AFAICT.